# In Matlab, how can I represent a zip file of images (all 32x32 pixels) as a matrix where each column is a single image?

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, matrix

I have a zip file of 10,000 32x32 images. I want to create a matrix where each column corresponds to the matrix representation of that image in vector form.

For example if U is my final matrix, column 1 of U will have 1024 values, and the command

```
imagesc(reshape(U(:,1),32,32))
```

will give me the first image.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question, viz. read the files in and then store them in the columns. Is there something specific you are having trouble with?

Comment: Are there 1 or 3 colour channels? i.e. is it B&W or RGB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care with the number of channels. Assuming you have RGB files, then something like the following will work.

```
U = zeros(1024, 10000, 3, 'uint8');
for idx = 1:10000
    filename = sprintf('file_%06d.png', idx);
    data = imread(filename);
    U(:,idx,:) = reshape(data,[],1,3);
end
```

Then you have to write

```
imagesc(reshape(U(:,1,:),32,32,3))
```

Alternatively, you can avoid reshaping using a 4-D array:

```
U = zeros(32, 32, 3, 10000, 'uint8');
for idx = 1:10000
    filename = sprintf('file_%06d.png', idx);
    U(:,:,:,idx) = imread(filename);
end

imagesc(U(:,:,:,1))
```